# Keycloak Bear-Only Client with and without Authorization Client Secret

Tags: keycloak, bearer-token

In keycloak when I set up a `Client` as a `bearer-only` Access Type and without Authorization I get the following config for installation on my server

```
{
  "realm": "API",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "https://example.com.au/auth/1.0",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "edge-server"
}
```

Then when I enable Authorization for that client it now includes the client secret:

```
{
  "realm": "API",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "https://example.com.au/auth/1.0",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "edge-server",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "33333333-4444-5555-6666-777777777777"
  },
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

So my question is why would my server need the `secret` when Authorizations are enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak Authorization policies can only be applied to confidential clients such as your backend REST API.